# Trying to return selected cell from UITableView but it just returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a custom cell class that has a function called setCell.

This takes a word and an image and sets a label and an imageview to them settings.

That works fine and is called during the cell setup.

The problem is when I try to get the currently selected cell text, it just returns nil.

Below is current 'didSelectRow' function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

    let currentCell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

    println(currentCell.textLabel!.text) //This returns nil
}
```

Bellow is my custom cell setup functions:

```
func setCell(text: String, imagetext: String) {
    if var image = self.myImage {
        image.image = UIImage(named: imagetext)
    }

    if var label = self.myLabel {
        label.text = text
        println(label.text) //Prints out the items that are in the cells, which is what I want it to do.
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why my code is returning nil?

EDIT: Thank you to the suggestions so far, but I just found out that if I print out `cell.labelText.text` after calling the `setCell` function on it, it just prints out nils.

```
cell.setCell(category, imagetext: theimage)
    println(cell.textLabel!.text) //I have 7 items in the list so it just print out nil 7 times.
```

Why is it not being set after calling the function on it?

Comment: Is `currentCell` nil before you try to print out its text?

Comment: Set a break point before you try to print out the text, and see if the cell has the properties you would expect it to

Comment: This is what is being printed to the console if I do `println(currentCell)`:
`<computing.TableViewCell: 0x7f8a38565880; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 600 144); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f8a3861bd30>>`. Computing is the name of the app and TableViewCell is the name of my custom cell file. (This changes slightly each option I click.)

Comment: why do you call `indexPathForSelectedRow()`? The requested index path is passed as a parameter and is a non-optional value

Comment: Printing out the cell won't provide the correct information. If you set a break point where you're trying to print the cell out, and when the app pauses execution, it will provide you with an overview of all the currently instantiated objects to the left of the debugger. You should be ale to see if the cell has the properties you would expect by dropping it down and looking through it.

Answer (score 0):

The indexPath and tableView are passed in as parameters and should be used to do what you're trying to do:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as CustomTableViewCellClass!;

    println(currentCell.textLabel!.text) //This returns nil
}
```